# Split a string of words and numbers and save some of its number elements c++

Tags: c++, string

I would like to find a way to split a string, composed by numbers (int) and words by space, and save some of its elements. 
I've got, for example the string (saved in the variable "row":
" 1 120 130 10 Dear_167 5" 
and I want to save 120 130 10 and 5..in a vector v.
I write a code such as:

```
int elements;
istringstream line_stream(row);

line_stream>>elements>>elements; //to skip the first number of row, 1
v[0]=elements; //so I save 120 in v[0]
line_stream>>elements;
v[1]=elements; //so I save 130 in v[1]
line_stream>>elements;
v[2]=elements; //so I save 10 in v[2]
line_stream>>elements>>elements;
v[3]=elements; //to save 5 in v[3]
```

My problem is that in v[3] I find 0.. 
I think it's because my variable elements is an int type, but I'm stuck now on this problem although maybe it's not difficult to solve.

Thanks

Comment: Have you already resized the vector?  `v[3]` does not create an element, it assigns to an already existing element ... so if it doesn't already exist you are assigning to an arbitrary memory location. Try replacing `v[3]` with `v.at(3)` and see if it throws an exception. I'm voting to close the question because you didn't provide enough information to show what's happening.

Comment: You should try looking into [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/); might make your implementation a lot easier

Comment: @MrDuk, good grief, no! `strtok` is an abomination, [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/libs/tokenizer/) would be better

Comment: As someone working on a project that I cannot easily implement third-party libs, would you mind elaborating for me? What about it makes it an "abomination"?

Comment: @MrDuk, it has an error-prone interface, it relies on static storage, and it destroys its input. Not to mention that it works on a `char*` which makes it inconvenient to use with `std::string`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Any non-3rd-party alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

```
line_stream>>elements;
v[1]=elements; //so I save 130 in v[1]
```

An easier way to do that is:

```
line_stream >> v[1];
```

However that assumes the element at `v[1]` already exists, if it doesn't then you need to resize the vector first.

```
line_stream>>elements>>elements;
```

This will not work if a word in the stream is `Dear_1675` because that cannot be read into an `int`, so the stream will be put into a failed state and you won't be able to read anything else from it.  To ignore arbitrary (non-integer) words read into a `string`.

This should do what you want:

```
std::string ignore;
std::istringstream line_stream(row);
v.resize(4);    
line_stream >> ignore >> v[0] >> v[1] >> v[2] >> ignore >> v[3];
```

You should also check for errors (if you'd done that you'd have found the stream failed in your own code):

```
std::string ignore;
std::istringstream line_stream(row);
v.resize(4);    
if (line_stream >> ignore >> v[0] >> v[1] >> v[2] >> ignore >> v[3])
{
  // read everything OK
}
else
{
  // row could not be read, did not match expected format
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Jonathan!  I'm going to try in this way, I think that's right! :)